# GAE update multiple records from localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, localhost

I am using Google App Engine on localhost. I have a datastore about Books with a `summary` text field. Many of the `summary` entries have the following two lines which I want to change to the succeeding one line:

TO BE REPLACED:

```
Many, many years ago
In a land far, far away
```

REPLACEMENT:

```
Once upon a time,
```

To make the changes thru the `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive` console, what would be the query I execute?

EDIT:

each `summary` field contain about two paragraphs of text, about 20 lines. Within those paragraphs, I need to find two specific lines and replace them with one specific line. In other words, I am not seeking to replace the entire summary content with new content.

Answer (score 0):

In the [interactive console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#The_Development_Console), you should be able to do something like this:

```
to_replace = """
             Many, many years ago
             In a land far, far away
             """
replace_with = 'Once upon a time,'

to_change = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE summary = :1", to_replace)
for entity in to_change:
    entity.summary = replace_with
    entity.put()
```

Comment: I get the following error `File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 296, in class_for_kind
    raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind)
KindError: No implementation for kind 'Book'`. But I do have entities. If I go to `Datastore Viewer` and click `list entities`, all are entities show up.